# How to exclude some tables from RDS Mysql replication

Tags: mysql, replication, rds

i have a cluster structure on RDS (master/slave)...and all the temporary tables created on the master are replicated on the slave. I don't want that....

I want that statements like:

> create temporary table tmp as (select * from tb);

...do not gets replicated.

I would want that NO temporary table were replicated. I realize now that i must user the option "replicate-ignore-table=name" ...

But any one knows how t do that on RDS? I think i have to user the client tool right?

Someone has an example?

Comment: there any option on "parameter group" that allow me to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Indeed,  RDS contains a section call `Parameter Groups`.

(UPDATE)

For RDS Mysql, there is no such options. Although `SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G` or `SHOW MASTER STATUS\G` will show those parameter.

For Mariadb 10, you can select those allowed custom RDS parameter e.g. `replicate_ignore_db` and create a parameter group, then attach to RDS instance `DB Parameter Group`.

Comment: no, RDS parameter groups do not have that option.... i opened a ticket on amazon, and they said that this is an old request that are not available yet....

Comment: @costamatrix Just notice it is only available for Mariadb10, which I assume it mysql should have it, but not.

Answer (score 0):

You can also switch your binlog format to ROW instead of STATEMENT/MIXED.

This because temporary tables in ROW binlog format are not replicated.

Source: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-features-temptables.html

Edit: In RDS MariaDB only, you can use the following options:

- replicate_ignore_db
- replicate_ignore_table
- replicate_wild_ignore_table

Source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.MariaDB.Parameters.html

Comment: This answer is incorrect, or outdated two months, later. One is unable to modify these parameters on the parameter group editor now.